# Cpp create string creation without initialization

Tags: c++, string, filestream

I want to read the contents of a file into a string.

```cpp
string contents(size, '\0'); -> size was determined above using the file.seekg and file.tellg.
file.read((char*) contents.data(), size);
```

Now, I know that the contents of the string will be overwritten in file.read, so there's no need to initialize the the string to null characters.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
std::string contents(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file},
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
```

But it may not be faster. Either way the initialization is likely to be very fast in comparison to reading from the drive.

Comment: "it may not be faster." Why?